# What does Dojo consider a XHR request error?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

When doing AJAX through Dojo we can pass two callbacks, one to execute after a successfull request and one to execute after an error:

```
dojo.xhr("GET",{
    url: myURL,
    content: messageContents,
    load: function(returnData, ioArgs){
        //This is called on success
    },
    error: function(returnData, ioArgs){
        //This is called on failure
    }
});
```

I couldn't find in the documentation **what is defined as an error**. I'd guess anything with a return code >= 400 but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, an unsuccessful HTTP response code.  The [determination is made](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/browser/tags/release-1.6.0/dojo/_base/xhr.js#L771) by calling [dojo._isDocumentOk](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/browser/tags/release-1.6.0/dojo/_base/_loader/hostenv_browser.js#L219) which as you'll see basically accepts 2xx and 304 plus some browser-quirk stuff.

Comment: Hi, would the error code get triggered if lets say we couldn’t locate or contact the server? or is it only triggered when we receive an error code from the server?

Comment: It should trigger an error in all these cases, but there's a [known bug](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/15372) in Dojo 1.7 and 1.8