# Servlet response format for dojo xhrPost error handler

Tags: dojo, xmlhttprequest

To trigger the error handler for dojo's `xhrPost`, is there a specific format in which the server response is to be sent? Or just setting the status code to the required error code in the `HttpServletResponse` object does the work.

Thanks,
RR

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721949/what-is-considered-and-ajax-request-error-in-dojo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to set the appropiate HTTP status code in the `HttpServletResponse`. I think anything greater than or equal to 400 will be considered an error by the XHR object.

Of course you can also send actual content in your response (via its output stream) and set its content type. You'll receive that in your handler as well:

```
dojo.xhrPost({
  url: '/request',
  load: function(data, ioargs) { /* ... */ },
  error: function(error, ioargs) {
    // error is a Javascript Error() object, but also contains 
    // some other data filled in by Dojo
    var content = error.responseText;   // response as text
    var status = error.status;          // status code
  }
});
```

You can also get `responseText` and `status` from `ioargs.xhr`, which is the full `XmlHttpRequest` object.