# Dojo error handling in ajax methods

Tags: dojo

Under what conditions does error of xhr methods get called? Even when the response is 200, the code in error is called. I'm using the xhrPost method.

Update:

```javascript
dojo.xhrPost({
url: url,
handleAs: respType /* json */,
content: data,
load: onServerResponse,
error: onHttpError
})
```

```javascript
function onServerResponse(response, ioArgs) {
    if(onResponse !== null) {
        onResponse(response);
    }
}
```

```javascript
function onHttpError(error, ioArgs) {
    if (showHttpError === true) {
        var errMsg = "";
        switch (ioArgs.xhr.status) {
            case 0: errMsg = "Please check Web Server status."; break;
            case 404: errMsg = "HTTP (404): Requested Page Not Found"; break;
            case 500: errMsg = "HTTP (500): The server reported an Error"; break;
            default: errMsg = "Unhandled HTTP error - " + ioArgs.xhr.status;
        }
        ConsoleUtils.showNotificationAlertDialog(errMsg, ConsoleConstants.INFORMATION);
    }
}
```

These are the response headers from Firebug:

Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type    application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Date    Sun, 18 Dec 2011 18:06:54 GMT

The response body
{"message":"Kiosk successfully deleted","success":true}

Despite a return status of 200, the alert dialog is called.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is considered and AJAX request error (in Dojo)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721949/what-is-considered-and-ajax-request-error-in-dojo)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've updated my question with the code snippets and firebug contents.

Comment: Can you post your onResponse method ?

Comment: Check that your `onServerResponse` method doesn't throw an error.

Comment: @Philippe `function onDeleteResponse(response) { 
 KioskTable.store.deleteItem(records[0]); 
 KioskTable.store.save();
 KioskTable.store.fetch();
}` Btw, I'm working with a JsonRestStore

Comment: I guess the error comes after the first 200 status... when you invoke onResponse(response);

Comment: @Philippe You are right, records[0] is not available in the scope of the onDeleteResponse callback and this was the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

in your onServerResponse function you use a var called onResponse.
Since you're doing : onResponse() i can only guess onResponse is a function.
Then your test if(onResponse !== null) does not seem appropriate, maybe you wanted to tests response.

if you wanted to test for the function's existance, you might want to check typeof onResponse == "function"

Also sicne you are calling a function in there, make sure the function is within the right scope...
You might then want to use load: dojo.hitch(theScopeWhereOnResponseFunctionExists, onServerResponse)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just fought with this problem for a while and found the explanation.

If your xhrget returns a 200, but the load function throws an unhandled exception, dojo will treat this as an error and call the error function.